# varchar or decimal data type for minutes, seconds, milliseconds

Tags: sql, mysql, time, types

I have a MySQL database table with cross country running times in it. I am at a fork in the road and questioning whether I should convert the current datatype for the running times (varchar) to a decimal.

The one aspect which attracts me to the varchar datatype is that I don't have to convert the incoming running results (parsed via a php script) to seconds and then back again when it is retrieved dynamically. My processing script ensures that each time is 8 characters long unless an athlete DNFs (Did not finish) which is also information that I'd like to store. The DNF appears as "DNF" in the results.

So should a running time be stored as 17:40.57 or 1060.57? What are the advantages and disadvantages to each? Is there a better datatype than what I have already assumed as the correct types?

Also, if you elect 1060.57 as your answer, then how would I logically store DNFs or DNSs?

Comment: It'd help to demonstrate what format you mean by "17:40.57" - most will assume that to be hh:mm:ss

Comment: For new users: [**Storing time with milliseconds in database**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10400/storing-time-with-milliseconds-in-database)

Answer (score 5):

I had originally suggested TIME and DATETIME data types, but was unaware that [MySQL does not store microseconds in a column of any temporal data type (IE: TIME, DATETIME, etc)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

FLOAT is obvious poor - even MySQL states it should only be used when precision is not a concern.

VARCHAR/CHAR isn't a great idea, because there's no means to enforce consistency of the format.  You could mix mm:ss:ff and the decimal format - both would be accepted, but would obviously look odd when displayed.

DECIMAL would be the best choice, for sake of data consistency & validation given the limitations of MySQL.  But it means custom functionality to get info out if you want different formatting, which would've been available if MySQL's temporal functions supported enough precision.

Other free databases, like PostgreSQL, SQL Server Express or Oracle Express might be worth considering as an alternative for sake of better data type support.

Comment: I assume the decimal piece is important, which cannot be stored in a TIME. If zen wants to use TIME, he'll need an additional column for milliseconds. He needs additional columns for the DNF and DNS entries, too.

Comment: @theazureshadow: The decimal is just *formatting/presentation* - that's what functions like [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) are for.

Comment: @OMG_Ponies: from the docs: "any microseconds part is discarded from values stored into TIME columns"

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Thank you for your response. I appreciate you taking the time to answer and value your input. nice name btw, lol.

Answer (score 1):

I'd store it as a `DECIMAL` number of seconds, with additional columns to store the DNFs or DNSs.  If you want, you can use a single enum for DNF and DNS, since they are mutually exclusive (assuming DNS is Did Not Start). This allows `SUM`, arithmetic, etc. Storing as a `VARCHAR` doesn't allow any interesting processing or filtering.

**EDIT:** changed to `DECIMAL`, for precision.

Comment: You should **never** use floating-point types for currency if you care about precision. You'll experience all sorts of weird rounding and comparison errors.

Comment: I'm happy with TIME or DATETIME, but you *cannot* store milliseconds, which will mean zen must use a separate column. Again: "microseconds cannot be stored into a column of any temporal data type"

Comment: "Storing as a VARCHAR doesn't allow any interesting processing or filtering"... the one thing I have been doing is keeping this table ordered by the "time" field. By default, this places DNFs at the bottom of all the table rows. I thank you for all your responses though. This is an interesting debate in my opinion and it's interesting to see how others would approach this.

Comment: Well, it really comes down to what matters in your implementation (both now and in the future). I think all three options (VARCHAR, TIME + milliseconds, DECIMAL) have good arguments, and I certainly wouldn't want to argue that there was a universally best answer.